# get rid of the curse

Tags: curse

Assalamu aleykum! I wanted to ask something. My grandfather's grandfather on my mother's side fell in love with a married woman and ran away with her to another city. The woman's husband cursed them. If the curse touches the descendants of that person, will it affect us? If there is an effect, what should we do to get rid of it? If there is no effect, what should we do for Allah to forgive this sin?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wa alaikum assalam!
It's important to note that Islam emphasizes personal responsibility for one's actions and sins. The concept of "curse" or negative consequences from the past sins of ancestors isn't a central tenet of Islamic belief. While some people may believe in the idea of generational curses, it's not a universally accepted concept in Islam.

In Islam, each individual is accountable for their own actions, and sins are not inherited from one generation to another.
The Quran clearly states in Surah Al-An'am (6:164) that

> **"No bearer of burdens will bear the burden of another."**

This means that you are not responsible for the actions of your ancestors, and their sins do not affect you in a direct, metaphysical way.